# New to Key-Value-Observing; why am I unable to monitor the value of an int in my AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++, key-value-observing

I have a public variable in my Objective-C++ AppDelegate called `stepsCompleted`, so I access it in my table view controller with `[AppDelegate instance]->stepsCompleted`.

I want my table view controller to tell me when the value of that variable has changed, so I do the following in the `initWithCoder:` method that I know is being called:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"[AppDelegate instance]->stepsCompleted" options:0 context:NULL];
```

However, despite me changing `stepsCompleted` constantly in the AppDelegate, my method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

}
```

Is never called.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[AppDelegate instance]->stepsCompleted` is not a property.

Comment: (Remember, what KVO does is "hook" the setter method.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different problems with your code. First of all, Key-Value Observing is
a mechanism to observe *properties* of an object. It does not work with instance
variables. So you should declare "stepsCompleted" as a property of the application delegate instead of an instance variable:

```
@property (nonatomic) int stepsCompleted;
```

and set its value through the property accessor methods, e.g.

```
[AppDelegate instance].stepsCompleted = newValue;
```

Next, `"[AppDelegate instance]->c"` is not a key path, and you have to specify at least one observing option, e.g. `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew`.

To observe the "stepsCompleted" property of `[AppDelegate instance]`, it should be

```
[[AppDelegate instance] addObserver:self 
                         forKeyPath:@"stepsCompleted"
                            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                            context:NULL];
```

Comment: It still never calls the method. Is it due to the `->`?

Comment: It still doesn't call the method unfortunately.

Comment: @DougSmith: What is `[AppDelegate instance]`? I have tested it with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` and that worked.

Comment: @MartinR, your expertise is needed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438818/core-data-threading-and-lock-contention-issues

Comment: It simply returns `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`. Hmm.

Comment: @DougSmith: Is `stepsCompleted` set via the property accessor? Setting the instance variable directly does not trigger a change notification.

Comment: Note that he's setting an instance field, not a property.

Comment: It's not a property, no. It's declared as `@public    int stepsCompleted;`.

Comment: @DougSmith: You have to declare it as `@property int stepsCompleted;` and set the value via the property accessors, e.g. `self.stepsCompleted = 5`.

Answer (score 3):

Although it’s the quickest and easiest way, you don’t really need to declare an `@property` to use KVO, you just need to make sure that before you call willChange and didChange for the property correctly, and a way to access it.

For instance, in the most manual case, you could implement `stepsCompleted` like this:

```
@implementation SomeClass {
   int _stepsCompleted;
}

- (void)setStepsCompleted:(int)stepsCompleted;
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@“stepsCompleted”];
    _stepsCompleted = stepsCompleted;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@“stepsCompleted”];
}

- (int)stepsCompleted;
{
    return _stepsCompleted;
}

@end
```

Then if you observed the keyPath “stepsCompleted” on “someObject" you would get called when it changed, assuming you ONLY ever changed it by using its setter, for example via:

```
[self stepsCompleted:10];
```

But since Apple introduced properties, the above can be shortened to the exactly equivalent:

```
self.stepsCompleted = 10;
```

---

But that’s still a whole lot of code for the setter and getter, and you don’t have to write all that, because Apple did a couple cool things in the last several years. One is the @property notation, which basically writes the above set/get code for you (with some extra good stuff thrown in). So now you can just put in your .h file:

```
@property int stepsCompleted;
```

And those two methods will be written for you. As long as you make sure you ONLY use the dot-notation or call the setter directly, KVO will work.

Comment: A property is essentially indistinguishable from having a setter and getter method of the appropriate names.

Comment: @WilShipley - What you're trying to explain is good and could be used by the OP to use KVO on a local variable. However in your example you do have a property, even though you don't declare it as such, the `setStepsCompleted`/`stepsCompleted` pair make it so. As with any user-written setter or getter KVO works on these methods *without* any calls to `willChangeValueForKey:` & `didChangeValueForKey:`, these methods are intended for when the backing variable is not changed by the setter method, as KVO by defaults works off that method. So what you have is *nested* notification to KVO...

Comment: I was trying to give a high-level overview of how it works, since the OP didn’t seem clear on the concept. You’re right they now work without calling the willChangeValueForKey:, because the compiler adds the willChange/didChange for you. I wanted any reader to understand what’s going on under the hood: that you can KVO on *anything* that you call didChange... for. (Even if there’s no property backing it up.)

Comment: @WilShipley - What I was trying to convey is that the compiler does not add those calls to the setter. KVO uses a runtime mechanism to observe property changes - if no observer is ever created then there is no involvement of KVO, KVO is not part of the generated setter.

Comment: CRD is (mostly) correct. Automatic KVO support is done using dynamic subclasses generated at runtime. Mike Ash has an excellent [article](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html) on the subject. Note though that you *don't* have to be changing a backing instance variable to get free KVO notifications. The setter need only be properly named, regardless of what it's doing internally. The manual KVO change methods are for emitting notifications from methods other than a setter, or conditionally (after disabling auto notifications with +automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:).

Comment: That's all nitpicking and probably irrelevant to the OP, though, and Wil's answer is very helpful. So of course, +1.